# PY2EXE: How to output "*_D.PYD" file (debug) and use MSVCR80D.DLL?

Tags: python, windows, py2exe

The debug configuration of my app is built against:

```
  PYTHON25_D.DLL
  MSVCR80D.DLL
```

We use Python .PYD files in our application. Some of these .PYD are .PY converted by PY2EXE to .PYD.

When I run PY2EXE on MYSCRIPT.PY, I get the following .PYD and dependencies:

```
MYSCRIPT.PYD
  PYTHON25.DLL
  MSVCR71.DLL
  KERNEL32.DLL
```

What I *want* is the debug version, built against the same C runtime library my app uses (MSVCR80D.DLL).

How can I convert MYSCRIPT.PY into:

```
MYSCRIPT_D.PYD                 <-- debug version of .PYD end with "_D"
  PYTHON25_D.DLL               <-- debug version of Python
  MSVCR80D.DLL                 <-- ver 8.0, Debug
  KERNEL32.DLL
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the MS debug dlls are nondistributable - you must not give them avay.  However, py2exe will collect the debug versions of all dlls correctly if you run a debug version of Python, and a debug compiled version of py2exe.

Answer (score 0):

it won't work, beacuse MSVCR80D is a side by side runtime

You will need to either tell user to directly install MS runtime or manually also copy the manifest files.
Also the MSVCR71.DLL is not selected for you. It's for Python, so you may still need to keep it.